# How to remove a package on a debian-based system WITHOUT removing dependencies?

Tags: linux-mint, apt, dependencies, aptitude

I'm running Linux Mint, a Debian-based distro, and I want to remove a package WITHOUT removing its reverse dependencies; or I want to target the removal of one package without removing anything else.

For example:
I want to remove PACKAGE_A, but (PACKAGE_X, PACKAGE_Y, PACKAGE_Z) depend on PACKAGE_A and would be automatically removed. I need to keep X,Y,Z installed and only remove A. Unfortunately, if I were to reinstall X,Y,Z it would also reinstall PACKAGE_A.

For the particular package I'd like to remove, there are about 20 dependencies and some dependencies appear to be critical to proper GUI functionality.

On Arch Linux, the [pacman documentation](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Pacman) says:

> To remove a package, which is required by another package, without removing the dependent package:
>
> pacman -Rdd package_name

Since my Debian-based distro doesn't use pacman, how can I achieve the same functionality with apt-get, Aptitude, or the Mint Software Manager?

**EDIT:** Faheem Mitha's answer was exactly what I was looking for.

> dpkg -r --force-depends foo

That removed the package in question without removing the dependencies apt-get and the Mint Software Manager complained about.  Thank you!

Comment: Do you mean that you want to remove package P but not the packages that depend on P, or to remove package P but not the packages that P depends on?

Comment: This question is not clearly written. If could mean I want to remove package P without removing the dependencies of P, or remove P with removing the packages that depend on P. The former is trivial, so I assume you mean the latter.

Comment: Re: edit comment "**This community is so damn picky, I've been as clear as I can be. Downv**": No. While I understand that you got the answer you were looking for, you really didn't substantially clarify that you are talking about things that *depend* on the package in question rather than dependencies, which are things that the package in question depends upon. Voting to leave closed.

Comment: Editing in the accepted answer is duplication of information and a waste of bandwidth. Thanks have no place on SE either. Hence I voted not to reopen. Please read the help page, especially the part about no chit-chat, just questions (and answers).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to remove a package that other packages depend on, without removing those other packages as well. Bearing in mind this might not be a good idea, you can do this with.

```
dpkg -r --force-depends foo
```

for removal of a package (conf files are not removed).

```
dpkg -P --force-depends foo
```

for purge of a package (conf files *are* removed).

Example usage:

```
root@orwell:/home/faheem# dpkg -P --force-depends gcc-4.6-base:amd64
dpkg: gcc-4.6-base:amd64: dependency problems, but removing anyway as you requested:
 gcc-4.6 depends on gcc-4.6-base (= 4.6.3-14).
 libstdc++6-4.6-dev depends on gcc-4.6-base (= 4.6.3-14).
 g++-4.6 depends on gcc-4.6-base (= 4.6.3-14).
 cpp-4.6 depends on gcc-4.6-base (= 4.6.3-14).

(Reading database ... 454279 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing gcc-4.6-base:amd64 ...
Processing triggers for ccache ...
Updating symlinks in /usr/lib/ccache ...
```

It is occasionally useful to perform such an action. Of course, leaving the system in this broken/inconsistent state for any length of time is highly undesirable. However, given a chance, apt will restore balance to its universe as follows:

```
root@orwell:/home/faheem# apt-get -f install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libavdevice53 libavfilter2 libglade2-dev python-cairo-dbg python-cairo-dev python-gnupginterface python-gobject-2-dev
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
The following extra packages will be installed:
  gcc-4.6-base
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  gcc-4.6-base
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 62 not upgraded.
Need to get 142 kB of archives.
After this operation, 159 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? 
Get:1 http://debian.lcs.mit.edu/debian/ wheezy/main gcc-4.6-base amd64 4.6.3-14 [142 kB]
Fetched 142 kB in 7s (19.1 kB/s)                   
Selecting previously unselected package gcc-4.6-base:amd64.
(Reading database ... 454274 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking gcc-4.6-base:amd64 (from .../gcc-4.6-base_4.6.3-14_amd64.deb) ...
Processing triggers for ccache ...
Updating symlinks in /usr/lib/ccache ...
Setting up gcc-4.6-base:amd64 (4.6.3-14) ...
```