# Imagemagick: Installing Jpeg Decode Delegate with Existing Installation

Tags: software-installation, imagemagick, jpeg

I installed ImageMagick 7.0.8-11 Q16 x86_64 from source, and I didn't know that decode delegates are not automatically included when installing from source. I should have installed a binary of ImageMagick, which includes the jpeg decode delegate. The problem is that I can't uninstall ImageMagick because many other programs depend on it. So is there a way for me to install the [jpeg decode delegate](https://imagemagick.org/download/delegates/) for the existing ImageMagick installation?

Relevant information:

Linux Mint 19 Tara 64bit.

```
apt-cache policy imagemagick
imagemagick:
Installed: (none)
Candidate: 8:6.9.7.4+dfsg-16ubuntu6.4
Version table:
8:6.9.7.4+dfsg-16ubuntu6.4 500
500 http://mirror.atlantic.net/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 Packages
500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/main amd64 Packages
8:6.9.7.4+dfsg-16ubuntu6.3 -1
100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
8:6.9.7.4+dfsg-16ubuntu6 500
500 http://mirror.atlantic.net/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages

identify -version
Version: ImageMagick 7.0.8-11 Q16 x86_64 2018-09-18 https://www.imagemagick.org
Copyright: © 1999-2018 ImageMagick Studio LLC
License: https://www.imagemagick.org/script/license.php
Features: Cipher DPC HDRI OpenMP
Delegates (built-in): fontconfig freetype png x zlib
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is [this AskUbuntu post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/211627/how-to-add-support-for-the-jpeg-image-format) related to your issue? If so you can follow this advice:

**Install JPEG Encoding Library**

Following the information provided by user Samir Sabri in [this AskUbuntu post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/211627/how-to-add-support-for-the-jpeg-image-format), you will need to add the JPEG library.

> I fixed the problem by installing from source the jpeg encoding library available at <strike>http://www.ijg.org/files/jpegsrc.v8c.tar.gz</strike>. ***(Latest JPEG Library can be [found here](http://www.ijg.org/files/jpegsrc.v9c.tar.gz).)***
>
> ```
> cd /usr/local/src
> tar xvfz jpegsrc-v9c.tar.gz
> cd jpegsrc.v9c
> ./configure --enable-shared --prefix=$CONFIGURE_PREFIX
> make
> sudo make install
> ```
>
> Then I re-installed ImageMagick from source:
>
> ```
> cd /usr/local/src
> tar xvfz ImageMagick-[yourImagemagickVersion].tar.gz
> cd ImageMagick-[yourImagemagickVersion]
> export CPPFLAGS=-I/usr/local/include
> export LDFLAGS=-L/usr/local/lib
> ./configure --prefix=/usr/local \
>   --disable-static --with-modules \
>   --without-perl \
>   --without-magick-plus-plus \
>   --with-quantum-depth=8 \
>   --disable-openmp
>  make
>  sudo make install
> ```

Substitute your options if necessary. You should be able to now use `imagemagick` to identify, encode, and decode jpeg files.

**Uninstall and Reinstall**

If the above post is not related or does not work the best course of action would be to uninstall `imagemagick` and install it again.

You can uninstall a package that you installed from source following the advice in [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/87111/if-i-build-a-package-from-source-how-can-i-uninstall-or-remove-completely) by user Javier Rivera.

`cd` into the directory of the source package and run:

```
make uninstall
```

You may need root(sudo) permissions if that is how you built the package initially.

As user Javier Rivera points out, this will only work if the developer(s) of the source package have made uninstall scripts/rules. If they did not you will need to run `make -n install` to figure out the install steps and attempt to gracefully undo them.

You may also attempt to uninstall the package via `dpkg` by following the advice outlined in [this post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/183000/how-to-remove-a-package-on-a-debian-based-system-without-removing-dependencies).

> ```
> dpkg -r --force-depends foo
> ```

Will uninstall package `foo` while maintaining the packages that depend on `foo`. However this will create an unstable system. It would be advised to run `apt-get -f install` to help sort this out and pay attention to the output.

Looking at your `apt-cache policy` output you should be able to install a version of `imagemagick` from your repositories.

I recommend that you try to only install packages via your package manager. This makes it easier to manage your system and should work to avoid situations like this.

Please comment if you have any questions or issues with this answer. I highly suggest you read through each link I have provided thoroughly before attempting the commands. I appreciate feedback to correct any misconceptions and to improve my posts. I can update my answer as needed.

Best of Luck!

Comment: I've followed the directions up to the point that I'm to re-install ImageMagick from source. Everything goes well until I get to the `make` step, and then I get this error: `root@koipty-Surface-Pro-2:/usr/local/src/ImageMagick-7.0.8-27# make
make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.`

Comment: Is there a makefile in your current path? When you ran the `./configure` step as specified in [the official documentation](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/install-source.php) it should create the makefile.

Comment: There are two files with "make" in the title, `Makefile.am` and `Makefile.in`.

Comment: @user8547 too be clear, you ran the configure script and the output created those makefiles? Is there a reason you need this version of Imagemagick and not the one found in your repos? If you do not use APT to manage your packages you will need to configure from source every time you want to update...

Comment: Yes, the configure step ran fine. I tried to find 7.08.11, but it's not in the repository: https://www.imagemagick.org/download/releases/. I'd rather use APT, but isn't that too late, since I already installed it from source?

Comment: Not at all, you can uninstall it and then install it via apt. I have included those instructions in my answer. Is there specific features that 7.08.11 has that you require that 6.9.7.4 is missing? If you absolutely need the newer version then you will need to make sure that you completely uninstall imagemagick before attempting to install from source again. Were you unable to add the jpeg libraries as specified? You may need to edit your question to re-clarify the exact issues going on here. Keep things as simple as possible you know?